# C program stuck in infinite-loop-like nautre but without printing any variables

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying K&R exercise 1-29 and honestly I'm stumped by what my program is doing. Upon inputting a small text file with gcc, the program just runs forever as if there's an infinite loop. Reading through my loops again I can't see any obvious mistakes, so I tried to print different variables to see what's happening, but nothing's printing to the command line - even the variable i from the very first for loop, not even once. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define tabStop 10
#define maxInput 1000

int main(){

int i, c, b;
int m, t = 0;
int index, index2;
char input[maxInput];
int nonBlank;

for (i = 0; i<maxInput-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF; ++i){
    if (c != ' '){
        input[i] = c;
    }
    else {
        index = i; /*stores location in character array at start of blanks*/
        for (b = 0; c == ' '; ++b, ++i); /*counts the number of blanks (b) until the next non-blank character*/
        nonBlank = input[i]; /*saves the first seen non-blank character to be re-added later (as getchar() will have taken it in from input and will now stay at that point of the input)*/
        index2 = i; /*stores location in character array at end of blanks*/
        if (b >= tabStop){ /*if the tab space fits inside the number of blanks, otherwise there is nothing to be done*/
            while (t < b){
                t += tabStop;
                ++m;
                }
        for (int x = 0, i = index; i != index2 && x <= m; ++i, ++x){ /*loops over the number of tabs to be added starting from the first blank in the array found up until the first non-blank*/
                input[i] = '\t';
                }
            while (i != index2){ /*if i did not reach index2 before x surpassed m, there exist remaining spaces to be filled with blanks*/
                input[i] = ' ';
                ++i;
                }
            }
            input[i] = nonBlank; /*puts the first seen non-blank character into place, as getchar() has already covered it and so it wouldn't otherwise be added like other non-blanks*/
        }
    }

input[i] = '\0';

printf("%s", input);

return 0;
```

}

Here's the inputted text file:

```
hello           there       world
```

Comment: Here `for (b = 0; c == ' '; ++b, ++i); ` condition always true, `c` is always same. You need to modify it to break the loop.

Comment: I was under the impression that using c to check a condition would call the getchar() function again and move along in the input file to the next character. Furthermore, this wouldn't explain why putting a printf or putchar for i at the top of the first for loop never prints anything to the termimal.

Comment: @lukepanayi Using `c` to check a condition does not change the value of `c`, and certainly does not call `getchar()` again.

Comment: printf is buttered, so does not output anything to the console until you flush the buffer or print a newline character. Since you have an infinite loop (by not changing c), the program never gets to the end and never flushes the output buffer.

Comment: @user3386109 yea I realised that shortly after making that comment. Having (c=getchar()) in the for loop fixed the problem - I don't know what I was thinking there!

Comment: @fredk that's not the printf I was referring to - in the question I said that even putting a printf at the start of the first for loop doesn't print anything, which confuses me, so that's another thing I was hoping to have explained.

Comment: Hey luke, if you solved this problem, please consider either answering your own question (and mark the answer as accepted) or deleting your question. Cheers!